# How to sum fields of collection elements without mapping them first (like foldLeft/reduceLeft)?

Tags: scala, collections, sum, mapreduce, higher-order-functions

Consider this class:

```
 case class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, age: Int)
 val persons = Person("Jane", "Doe", 42) :: Person("John", "Doe", 45) :: 
               Person("Joe", "Doe", 43) :: Person("Doug", "Don", 65) :: 
               Person("Darius", "Don", 24) :: Person("Dora", "Don", 20) :: 
               Person("Dane", "Dons", 29) :: Nil
```

To get the sum of the age of all persons, I can write code like:

```
persons.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.age)
```

But if I want to use `sum`, I need to map the value first and the code looks like this:

```
persons.map(_.age).sum
```

How can I use the `sum` method *without* creating some intermediate collection?

(I know that such an "optimization" most probably doesn't have any real performance difference when not run in a tight loop and I also know about lazy views and so on.)

Is it possible to have code like

```
persons.sum(_.age)
```

doing what `foldLeft`/`reduceLeft` does?

Comment: I guess `sumBy` (cf. `sortBy`) would be a reasonable extension for the collection library.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. Although I can't really decide between a) Overloading sum (many devs don't like overloading) b) sumBy (consistent with SortBy) and c) sumOf (nicer to read, like "totalAge is defined as persons sumOf age").

Comment: Ugh, library extension?  Next we'll need `prodOf` and `maxOf` and `minOf`.  And then those of us who like median or mean or entropy or (etc.) will feel left out.  A good old `mapReduce` might be nice.  But beyond that I think it's better for all involved to get used to folding and/or views.

Comment: @Rex Kerr: Uh? We already have `maxBy` and `minBy`! That's the point I am making here.

Comment: @soc - Argh.  Well, it's not in 2.8.1.  And I think it's foolish to do for 2.9.

Comment: Why? Following these arguments, we could remove _everything_ except `filter`, `flatten` and `map`, because those are just some "convenenience" method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method `sum` in the library doesn't work this way, but you could write your own which does:

```
def mySum[T, Res](f: T => Res, seq: TraversableOnce[T])(implicit num: Numeric[Res]) = 
  seq.foldLeft(num.zero)((acc, b) => num.plus(acc, f(b)))
```

You could also add an implicit conversion so you can call it like `seq.sum(f)` instead of `mySum(f, seq)` (you may need a different name than `sum` to avoid conflicts):

```
case class SumTraversableOnce[T](val seq: TraversableOnce[T]) { 
  def sum[Res](f: T => Res)(implicit num: Numeric[Res]) = mySum(f, seq)(num) 
}

implicit def toSumTraversableOnce[T](seq: TraversableOnce[T]) = 
  SumTraversableOnce(seq)
```

or, since Scala 2.10,

```
implicit class SumTraversableOnce[T](val seq: TraversableOnce[T]) { 
  def sum[Res](f: T => Res)(implicit num: Numeric[Res]) = mySum(f, seq)(num) 
}
```

Comment: I can't get it to compile here (2.9 trunk). I think `0` should be `num.zero`.

Answer (score 13):

You answered is yourself. Just use `view`:

```
persons.view.map(_.age).sum
```

To convince yourself by examining the workflow:

```
persons.view.map { p =>
  println("invoking age")
  p.age
}.map { x =>
  println("modifing age")
  x + 0
}.sum
```

Vs:

```
persons.map { p =>
  println("invoking age")
  p.age
}.map { x =>
  println("modifing age")
  x + 0
}.sum
```

Comment: Well, `view` was exactly the thing i don't wanted to use. :-)

Comment: May I ask why you exclude `view`?

Comment: I wondered if I did miss a method which fills the gap between `sum` and `foldLeft`.

Comment: You didn't miss anything. `sum` is more or less your `foldLeft`: `def sum[B >: A](implicit num: Numeric[B]): B = foldLeft(num.zero)(num.plus)` (from Scala source). I don't know a to make something in-between without adding indirection.

Comment: Looks like someone just filed a ticket about it: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4276

Answer (score 0):

In Scala 3 you can create the following extension:

```scala
extension [T](iterable: Iterable[T])
  def sumBy[U](f: T => U)(using n: Numeric[U]): U = iterable.foldLeft(n.zero)((acc, elem) => n.plus(acc, f(elem)))
```